# Differences in JLabel when loading ttf font between Windows and Linux

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jlabel, truetype

I'm uploading the aller font in java with the following code:

```
private Font loadFont(final String path) {
    Font font = null;

    InputStream fontFile = null;
    fontFile = FontLoaderClass.class.getResourceAsStream(path);

    if (fontFile != null) {
        try {
            font = Font.createFont(Font.PLAIN, fontFile);
        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error with font format {}", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error accessing font {}", e);
        }
    }
    return font;
}
```

The font is loaded correctly:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Aller

the font is set to all ".font" changing the default settings for java application, but in Linux is shown correctly but Windows isn't.

```
private Font buildFont(final String key, final int size) {
    Font f = loadFont(ALLER_LT_FONT_PATH);
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(f);
    if (f == null) {
        f = (Font) UIManager.get(key);
    }
    f = f.deriveFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, size);
    return f;
}
```

Linux shows:
[image: linux image pick]

Windows shows:
[image]

As you can see in the images, there is some cut off in Windows that causes the image not to be shown correctly.

Has anyone experienced with this issue before?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong...They look same except that label on Windows seems a bit larger.

Comment: In windows is clearly not smooth as is in linux.

Comment: 1. Use PNG images instead of JPEG in such a case. 2. Are you sure the problem isn't due to [system cleartype settings](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+configure+anti+aliasing&aq=f&oq=windows+configure+anti+aliasing&aqs=chrome.0.57.12896j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=windows+configure+cleartype&oq=windows+configure+clear&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i30j0i8i30l2.3729.4520.0.5901.5.5.0.0.0.0.289.1330.2-5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.ZBXVMBdk6hA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45960087,d.bGE&fp=fa702e9da3b617a&biw=1600&bih=775)?

Comment: they are font, not images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

find two small demos attached, wich enables antialiasing for Swing components respectivly for draw operations.

for Swing components

```
// to enable antialiasing (AA) for Swing components
//
// either:
//    start the JVM with the option -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
//    see also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html#aaFonts
// or:
//    System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "on");
//    - you must call it before the first Swing component is rendered
//    - if AA it's on by default you must set it "off", otherwise you can't
//      toggle it inside the application

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import static java.awt.RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING;
import static java.awt.RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF;
import static java.awt.RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON;

public class SwingAntiAliasingDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "off");
        initGui();
    }

    public static void initGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 96);
        JPanel jpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel labelAA = new JLabel("Antialiasing ON") {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                graphics2d.setRenderingHint(KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        labelAA.setFont(font);
        labelAA.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        JLabel labelNoAA = new JLabel("Antialiasing OFF") {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                graphics2d.setRenderingHint(KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        labelNoAA.setFont(font);
        labelNoAA.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        jpanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 22, 95));
        jpanel.add(labelAA, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jpanel.add(labelNoAA, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setTitle("stackoverflow question 16304254");
        frame.getContentPane().add(jpanel);
        frame.setLocation(200, 200);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

for draw operations

```
// to enable antialiasing (AA) for draw operations

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import static java.awt.RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING;
import static java.awt.RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF;
import static java.awt.RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON;

public class DrawAntiAliasingDemo extends JFrame {

    private Font font;
    private Color backGroundColor;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawAntiAliasingDemo();
    }

    public DrawAntiAliasingDemo() {
        font = new Font("Serif", Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 96);
        backGroundColor = new Color(0, 22, 95);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        setTitle("stackoverflow question 16304254");
        setSize(850, 260);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D d = (Graphics2D) g;
        d.setColor(backGroundColor);
        d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        d.setFont(font);
        d.setPaint(Color.white);

        d.setRenderingHint(KEY_ANTIALIASING, VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        d.drawString("Antialiasing ON", 10, 115);

        d.setRenderingHint(KEY_ANTIALIASING, VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
        d.drawString("Antialiasing OFF", 10, 230);
    }
}
```

cheers
Frank

Comment: According to the JAVA doc (your link) "awt.useSystemAAFontSettings" is on by default and I just tested it and my desktop settings obviously say that AA should be used. That is your first example without the System.setProperty shows identical labels for me. So I guess that behavior is okay. If RamonBoza wants to make sure that his application uses AA regardless of the desktop settings he should use the JVM parameter solution which seems to be the easiest.

Comment: @Trilarion
The JVM checks automatially if the operating system support for AA is enabled or not. It can be cross checked with
    
`System.out.println(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.font.desktophints"));`

The JVM option "-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on" force the AA support on (with the operating systems default setting). If you want to use another setting, you could use one of the possiblbe values, described under the javadoc link.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that Windows OS isn't using ClearType. ClearType is an option, when enabled it smoothes the fonts. Sometimes it is disabled for tuning or performance reasons. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306527. Try to enable it.

To use ClearType for screen fonts:

1. Click Start, click Control Panel, click Appearance and Themes, and
   then click Display.
2. On the Appearance tab, click Effects.
3. Click to select the Use the following method to smooth edges of screen fonts check box, and then click ClearType in the list.

Comment: in fact, the application is executed in Windows 8 that has ClearType by default enabled, disabling it makes the application to work fine but Windows to does not look ok.

Comment: My suggestion was to enable it, *not* disable. Furthermore the rendering can lead to slight differences. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/faq-jsp-138165.html  - Section Text Rendering.

Comment: Will there be a need for tuning up of ClearType required though it might be enabled, as suggested in http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/make-text-easier-to-read-using-cleartype.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar issue before till I found this library in [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net) which is called Smooth Metal you can download it from [`Here`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smoothmetal/)

Library Home [Smooth Metal](http://smoothmetal.sourceforge.net/)

The `Smooth Metal` look and feel is an addition to some of the look and feels including with `Java`, enhancing them with `anti-aliased text`.

You would notice that `ClearType` option in Windows will not affect the Result...

After adding the jar file of the library in the class path I wrote this small java app that renders the `JLabel` and undo rendering with two `JButtons` the results were crystal clear:

Here is the code which you can test:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI;
import smoothmetal.SmoothLabelUI; // UI Class to set for the JLabel


public class LabelRender extends JFrame{

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("RENDER");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("UNDO");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("HELLO WORLD");

    public LabelRender(){
        setSize(600, 250);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("JLabel Renderer");


        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        label.setFont(new Font("Aller", Font.PLAIN, 70));
        label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        panel.add(label);
        panel2.add(button);
        panel2.add(button2);

        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        this.add(panel2, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        this.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setVisible(true);
        validate();


       // System.out.println(label.getUI());

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setUI(new SmoothLabelUI());
            }
        });

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setUI(new BasicLabelUI());
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new LabelRender();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,
when you run your example as 

    `java -cp .;smoothmetal.jar -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on LabelRender`

it confirms what I mentioned in my first example: "if AA it's on by default you must set it "off", otherwise you can't toggle it inside the application"
cheers, Frank